# Show jQuery real-time search results as <tr> elements on table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, loops

I have a real time filter on a table, as part of a ERP system. This is a text input in the foot of the table, in which user can type any part of the element's name contained on the DB, and table will show those matching.

This is the table's body:

```
<tbody>
<?php
while($registroBbdd = consultaRegistro($select)){
    $class="";
    $turn_id=$registroBbdd['tu_id'];
    $name=$registroBbdd['tu_name'];
    echo '<tr class="'.$class.'">
        <td><span class="tableContentRow">'.$registroBbdd['tu_name'].'</span></td>
        <td class="editColumn"><a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a></td>
        </tr>'; }}      ?>
</tbody>
```

And this is the function which selects those whose name matches typed characters:

```
$(document).on('keydown', searchSuggestions)

function searchSuggestions (e) 
{
    var cadena = $('input[name=turn_tableFilter]').val();

    if(cadena.length>2)
    {
        $updateUrl = 'config/forms/turn_conf/turn_search.php';
        $.post($updateUrl, {tu_abrev:cadena}).success(showSuggestions);
    }
}
```

This `searchSuggestions` function must be working fine, as it calls properly `showSuggestions` function, removing all `<tr>` contained on the table:

```
function showSuggestions (datos) {
$('tbody *').remove();}
```

The problem is how to show them. I need to make this last function something like a loop accumulating all matching results, and then show them in real time on my table with the same `<tr>` structure defined before. Any ideas of how could this be done? How can I bring that data from `turn_search.php` and give it a proper format?

Comment: I want to know how to build a loop based on results given on the turn_search.php document, wich has a "SELECT *...LIKE" taking user typed characters. That is having as a result all items on DB whose name contains typed characters. Well, I need to show that on my table. Hope I've explained properly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each key press, you need to send the request to the server passing the key parameter which was pressed. Based on that alphabet, php will fetch relevant records and display it. This goes on.

So create a div wrapping the while loop.

```
    <tbody>
    <div id = "searched_records"> <!--this one-->
    <?php
    while($registroBbdd = consultaRegistro($select)){
        $class="";
        $turn_id=$registroBbdd['tu_id'];
        $name=$registroBbdd['tu_name'];
        echo '<tr class="'.$class.'">
            <td><span class="tableContentRow">'.$registroBbdd['tu_name'].'</span></td>
            <td class="editColumn"><a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a></td>
            </tr>'; 
      }       ?> </div>
```

And then write the remove function in the below way. You basically dont delete the new div, it deletes the child elements.

```
function showSuggestions (datos) {
    $('#searched_records').empty();
    //add new data here
    $('#searched_records').html(datos);

}
```

Comment: I am about to try this, I'll tick if I solve this with your suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, not working but it seems to be on the way. the empty method does not work if the object is **$('#searched_records')**, does not make anything, but it does with tbody: **$('tbody *').empty();**, anyway empty is the correct method. On the other hand what is failing now is that no HTML is being added, as no HTML is being generated. Do I have to generate the HTML piece I want to show on a loop on the turn_insert.php file? Where do I generate the HTML that should result? Very grateful @Abhishek.

Comment: GOT IT. It brings me results, not inside the table, not formatted, but it brings results on real time. Very grateful.

Comment: Finally it brings me the right info on the right place qith each row correctly formated:
function showSuggestions (datos) {
    $('tbody *').empty();
 var resultados= datos;
    $('tbody').html(resultados);
}

Comment: Great !! Well Done !!